# Is there generic way to detach ArrayBuffer in any browsers?

Tags: javascript

I want to detach arbitrarily `ArrayBuffer`.
In d8(v8), i can detach ArrayBuffer using `%ArrayBufferNeuter(array.buffer);`.
But, i don't know how to do it without debugging option like above.
Is there some generic method to detach ArrayBuffer?

Comment: What do you mean by "detach"?

Comment: @Bergi That means free the current ArrayBuffer's backing_store

Comment: Ah, you mean detach the backing store from the buffer instance. No, there is no generic method to do that in the standards. You just let the buffer get garbage-collected.

Comment: @Bergi I heard somewhere that transferring `ArrayBuffer` from main thread to worker thread is one way to detach `main thread`'s ArrayBuffer. Does it right?

Comment: Hm, I guess so, but that's also transferring the buffer to another thread. I don't think there's a way to detach it when you just want to dispose of it. Or what are you actually looking for? What is the problem that you need to solve?

Answer (score 2):

You can now detach an `ArrayBuffer` by using [`structuredClone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) with `transferables` argument.

> An array of transferable objects in value that will be moved rather
> than cloned to the returned object.

```
// this detaches the buffer
structuredClone(arrayBuffer, { transfer: [arrayBuffer] });
```

```js
function moveBuffer(arrayBuffer) {
  return structuredClone(arrayBuffer, { transfer: [arrayBuffer] });
}

const buffer = new Uint8Array([1]).buffer;
const moved = moveBuffer(buffer);
console.log(buffer.byteLength === 0); // detached
console.log(moved.byteLength === 1);
```

---

You could also use (not yet fully supported), [`ArrayBuffer.prototype.transfer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer/transfer)

```js
const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(8);
console.log(buffer.detached); // false
const newBuffer = buffer.transfer();
console.log(buffer.detached); // true
console.log(newBuffer.detached); // false
```

Comment: I'd name that function `moveBuffer` though. If its purpose was to only detach the buffer, it shouldn't return a new one.

Comment: You're right :)

Answer (score 1):

Not yet, but [there is a proposal](https://github.com/domenic/proposal-arraybuffer-transfer/) to introduce such a method.

Answer (score 0):

```
function detachBuffer(buffer) {
  try {
    postMessage('', '', [buffer]);
  } catch { }
}
```

Comment: You could use a MessageChannel to avoid tripping out any message event listener: `new MessageChannel().port1.postMessage("", [buffer])`